# How can I map NEMA phases to lane IDs in SUMO?

Tags: sumo

I see SUMO supports NEMA tl logic, but I cannot find a way to map the NEMA phase (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8) to the corresponding incoming junction lanes. Is there a way to do so? I'm using Python and Traci